# How to have the same page in several places without interfering with navigation

Tags: angularjs

I am building a very large angular application.

Over 50 controllers and no end in site so far.

I have about 8 pages, that should show up in different contexts or work flows.

For example, there is a message page that lets you send messages.

There's about four ways to get to this page.

Now each of those way, I want to have a nav button at the top, that goes back to the previous section, or displays different information.

Otherwise they are all the same.

Currently I create a route for each of the four different ways to get to the page.
And a custom controller for each of those routes. ( trying to offload as much functionality as I can to services)

I have one of these kinds of pages setup, with different routes, but with the same controller.
I use a routeParam to if/else a bit of the logic.

This feels very hooky, as I'm duplicating way to many things.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look @ ui-router, its great for multiple parallel views like pairing main view to nav bar. Its a type of state machine, so going back to the previous section (that maintain their state) is doable.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Have a look @ this too:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views

Here's a basic demo:
http://plnkr.co/edit/kYPGZw?p=preview